# Sed and delete lines matching "String1 AND string 2"

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I can't find how to make that, I want to remove every line containing ACE and REE. only if both words are present.

```
sed -i '/ACE/d' $1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using awk, which would allow you to specify both patterns separately:

```
awk '!(/ACE/ && /REE/)' file
```

All lines are printed, except for those where both patterns match.

The advantage of this approach is that it would work regardless of the order in which the two strings appear.

To achieve an "in-place" edit, you can go for the standard approach:

```
awk '!(/ACE/ && /REE/)' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

i.e. output to a temporary file and then overwrite the source.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
sed -i '/ACE.*RRE/d' FileName
```

Or

```
sed -i '/\(ACE\|CH3\).*\(CH3\|ACE\)/d' FileName
```

**Example:**

```
cat sample
```

**Output:**

```
336 ACE CH3 1.00
123 ACE 321 test
This ACE for testing CH3
```

**Command:**

```
sed  '/ACE.*CH3/d' sample
```

**Output:**

```
123 ACE 321 test
```

Comment: is deleting the line when ACE or REE are present, I want to remove the line only when both are present.

Comment: Check with another answer , It should work for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you second answer is working, but it is not working with numbers.

Comment: Give me some sample line ?

Comment: 336 ACE CH3 1.00

    sed -i '/ACE.*CH3/d'

Comment: There is one catch here: The sequence of the 2 words. Probably you should add `sed -i '/ACE.*RRE/d;/RRE.*ACE/d' FileName` if you want it sequence independent...

Comment: @Kalanidhi: `\(ACE\|CH3\).*\(CH3\|ACE\)` will also match if one of the patterns occurs twice (e.g. "336 ACE ACE 1.00").

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match both words but you don't know the order you need to try both cases like so:

```
sed -i '/\(ABC.*DEF\)\|\(DEF.*ABC\)/d' FileName
```

It will match any row with **either** `ABC.*DEF` or `DEF.*ABC` and then remove it.

**NOTE:** With the pattern similar to the following you will also match the case where ABC occurs 2 times and DEF 0 times, and that is **not** what you want.

```
sed -i '/\(ABC\|DEF\).*\(ABC\|DEF\)/d' FileName
```